# Kubernetes - Volume not getting mounted when I scale the deployment pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, horizontalpodautoscaler

I have got a deployment.yaml and it uses a persistentvolumeclaim like so

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mautic-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: standard
```

I am trying to scale my deployment horizontally using (Horizontal Pod Scheduler) but when I scale my deployment, the rest of the pods are in `ContainerCreating` process and this is the error I get when I `describe the pod`

```
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volume
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try using a VolumeClaimTemplate

Comment: oh, I thought volumeclaimtemplates only work with statefulsets..

Comment: Sorry I'm short on time. I'm  going to try this quick

Comment: Howdy. Did some more reading. I don't know that this is possible. To scale out volumes you will probably need to go StatefulSets. Also lets clarify a few things. You have an HPA scaling out the replicas. When a new replica is created you want it to get it's own persistentVolume claim, but you are aware that when HPA scales it down it will lose the volume right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997598/bind-different-persistent-volume-for-each-replica-in-a-kubernetes-deployment

Comment: Ok I'm now quite convinced you should try a statefulset. It looks like HPA also supports those.

Comment: StatefulSets represent a set of Pods with unique, persistent identities and stable hostnames, they are suitable for deploying Kafka, MySQL, Redis, ZooKeeper, and other applications needing unique, persistent identities and stable hostnames.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is great if your app can scale *horizontally*. However, using a [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) with a `PersistentVolumeClaim` can be challenging when scaling *horizontally*.

#### Persistent Volume Claim - Access Modes

A `PersistentVolumeClaim` can be requested for a few different [Access Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes):

- ReadWriteOnce (most common)
- ReadOnlyMany
- ReadWriteMany

Where `ReadWriteOnce` is the most commonly available and is typical behavior for a local disk. But to scale your app horizontally - you need a volume that is available from multiple nodes at the same time, so only `ReadOnlyMany` and `ReadWriteMany` is viable options. You need to check what  what *access modes* are available for your *storage system*.

In addition, you use a *regional cluster* from a cloud provider, it spans over three *Availability Zones* and a volume typically only live in one *Availability Zone*, so even if you use `ReadOnlyMany` or `ReadWriteMany` access modes, it makes your volume available on multiple nodes in the same AZ, but not available in all three AZs in your cluster. You might consider using a **storage class** from your cloud provider that is replicated to multiple *Availability Zones*, but it typically costs more and is slower.

### Alternatives

Since only `ReadWriteOnce` is commonly available, you might look for better alternatives for your app.

**Object Storage**

Object Storage, or Buckets, is a common way to handle file storage in the cloud instead of using filesystem volumes. With Object Storage you access you files via an API over HTTP. See e.g. [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage).

**StatefulSet**

You could also consider [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) where each instance of your app get its own volume. This makes your app *distributed* but typically not *horizontally scalable*. Here, your app typically needs to implement replication of data, typically using [Raft](https://raft.github.io/) and is a more advanced alterantive.